# How to identify new users who fulfil the criteria

Tags: php, sql, dynamic, google-bigquery, analysis

I have a table with user_id,spend and order_date. I will be sending communications to users with spend greater than 200 based on 31 days from any day. I want to see how many new users will fulfil the criteria if I run the campaign for additional days. i.e on average how many users **new** fulfil the criteria if I run the communication for more days. I am only interested in new users.

Comment: I think you want to run some query on your table? The question is a bit vague, it sounds like you want to make some sort of prediction based on the past?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I will be using this information to estimate the duration of my campaign for A/B testing.